# How to have a page and custom-post-type on same hierarchy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am searching for a way to have "jobs" and a page with an "application form" in the same url-hierarchy in WordPress.

The jobs (CPT):

```
/jobs/engineer/
/jobs/ceo/
```

The application-form page (Page):

```
/jobs/application-form/
```

In my understanding its not possible to mix "posts" and "pages" in WordPress.

Maybe I have to help myself by adding "/detail/" or something else to the jobs.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my understanding its not possible to mix "posts" and "pages" in WordPress.

That's right, because post aren't hierarchical, but pages are.

When you register your custom post type using `register_post_type()` you can set it as hierarchical using the arguments `hierarchical`. The default value being false.

If you set `'hierarchical' => true` your custom post type will act like a PAGE, with hierarchical capabilities. If you set `'hierarchical' => false` your custom POST type will act like a post, without hierarchical capabilities.

Once this is done, after setting a custom post type as `jobs` with `'hierarchical' => true` and creating a parent page called `details` and a child page called `application-form` will get you `/jobs/details/application-form/`.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
  $args = [
    // ...
    'hierarchical' => true,
    // ...
  ];
  register_post_type( '_your_custom_post_type_slug_', $args );
} );
```

Comment: first i thought i got it. but i have to recheck. will get back to this with a feedback. thanks!

Comment: Ok, thanks again. I found a way for me to "hack" this without any /details/ url. I added a custom field "is_form_page" and set 1 post as my form-page. Then I changed my archive-query to loop only through the posts that have not the custom field value "true" for form-page. i have to set the ordering to 9999 and the date to 2020 and now its also ok to have it indexed by google with these settings.